# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar npm build en una página específica de un conjunto de páginas que fueron creadas en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un template de páginas hechas en React, la documentación no dá más información al respecto.

El problema que tengo es que al ejecutar "npm build" se construye todo y no una página en específico. Lo que deseo es que de la siguiente imagen, el comingSoon12.js al momento de construir sea el index principal para subirla a un hosting, pero soy novato, casi inexperto en React por lo que no sé que archivo puedo editar para lograr lo que deseo. Muchas gracias de antemano.

**Esta es la imagen con el contenido de las carpetas**

[image: Imagen del conjunto de páginas]

**Esta es la estructura del App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./assets/scss/style.scss";

import ComingSoon01 from "./pages/comingSoon01";
import ComingSoon02 from "./pages/comingSoon02";
import ComingSoon03 from "./pages/comingSoon03";
import ComingSoon04 from "./pages/comingSoon04";
import ComingSoon05 from "./pages/comingSoon05";
import ComingSoon06 from "./pages/comingSoon06";
import ComingSoon07 from "./pages/comingSoon07";
import ComingSoon08 from "./pages/comingSoon08";
import ComingSoon09 from "./pages/comingSoon09";
import ComingSoon10 from "./pages/comingSoon10";
import ComingSoon11 from "./pages/comingSoon11";
import ComingSoon12 from "./pages/comingSoon12";
import ComingSoon13 from "./pages/comingSoon13";
import ComingSoon14 from "./pages/comingSoon14";
import ComingSoon15 from "./pages/comingSoon15";
import ComingSoon16 from "./pages/comingSoon16";
import ComingSoon17 from "./pages/comingSoon17";
import ComingSoon18 from "./pages/comingSoon18";
import ComingSoon19 from "./pages/comingSoon19";
import ComingSoon20 from "./pages/comingSoon20";

import LandingPage from "./pages";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}
          component={LandingPage}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-one"}
          component={ComingSoon01}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-two"}
          component={ComingSoon02}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-three"}
          component={ComingSoon03}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-four"}
          component={ComingSoon04}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-five"}
          component={ComingSoon05}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-six"}
          component={ComingSoon06}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-seven"}
          component={ComingSoon07}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-eight"}
          component={ComingSoon08}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-nine"}
          component={ComingSoon09}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-ten"}
          component={ComingSoon10}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-eleven"}
          component={ComingSoon11}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-twelve"}
          component={ComingSoon12}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-thirteen"}
          component={ComingSoon13}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-fourteen"}
          component={ComingSoon14}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-fifteen"}
          component={ComingSoon15}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-sixteen"}
          component={ComingSoon16}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-seventeen"}
          component={ComingSoon17}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-eighteen"}
          component={ComingSoon18}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-nineteen"}
          component={ComingSoon19}
        />
        <Route
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/coming-soon-twenty"}
          component={ComingSoon20}
        />
        <Route exact component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es importar ese componente a tu `index.js`, o renombrar ese archivo para que se llame index.js y el otro index cambiarle el nombre. Ya que él comando construye todo el proyecto

Comment: No me funciono compa :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código funciona, tuve el mismo problema

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./assets/scss/style.scss";

import ComingSoon12 from "./pages/comingSoon12";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}
          component={ComingSoon12}
        />
       
        <Route exact component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que el archivo `comingSoon12.js` sea el principal lo debes importar desde `App.js`. Supongamos que `comingSoon12.js` tiene lo siguiente:

```
import React from 'react';


export function ComingSoon12(){
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  )
}
```

Lo puedes importar desde `App.js`

`import CommingSon12 from './pages/comingSoon12';`

y el archivo `App.js` tendría lo siguiente:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App(){
  return (
    <CommingSon12 />
  )
}
```

de esta forma, al hacer el build, tomará ese componente como principal.

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Acabe de editar mi pregunta con el contenido del App.js pero creo que la importacion ya esta hecha, quite todas las rutas y los imports de todos menos del comingSoon12.js pero me sale un error al hacer npm run build

Answer (score 1):

Lo conseguí hacer funcionar con este código

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./assets/scss/style.scss";

import ComingSoon12 from "./pages/comingSoon12";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}
          component={ComingSoon12}
        />
       
        <Route exact component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

No creo que el approach que estas siguiendo sea el correcto. En primera `npm build` no es precisamente un constructor de proyecto como lo estás asumiendo, y te entiendo, pues por el nombre a eso parece que se refiere. Puede leer [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664200/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-run-build) más sobre esto.

Ahora, React.js, tampoco funciona así como lo estás asumiendo. Que ahora el index.js sea construido en base a otro js file. Ese es el método tradicional de cómo trabajaban las páginas web y ahí si aplica el remplazo que estás tratando de hacer.

En las librerías de UI para javascript existe algo llamada State. Así que lo que te recomiendo para lograr que el componente comingSoon12.js sea ejecutado, necesitas saber qué State es el apropiado para llegar ahí, a partir del estado incial de la app.

Algo q te puedo ayudar a entender mejor como funciona [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)